# CakePHP 2.3 with SqlServer on debian squeeze

Tags: cakephp, sql-server-2008-r2, sybase

I'm confused about all the requirements to get cakephp 2.x to talk to MSSQL (2k8R2).  I'm running debian squeeze and installed php5-sybase.

I'd be using this as a second datasource defined as

```
public $qadb = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'login' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'database' => 'mydb',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

When I'm trying to run cake bake with this datasource I get

Error: Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created.

I looked at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php which references installing ODBC for linux, but I thought the sybase package would take care of what I need.  Any further info anyone has on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The CakePHP Sqlserver datasource points to the documentation you referred to and as you discovered as well: *The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows*. SQL-server support for PHP on Linux is a bit flunky, I'm not sure if CakePHP officially supports SQL-server on linux, or only via PDO?

Comment: It's a shame if this can't be done.  The ODBC driver references is only 64bit from what I can see.

Comment: I know, it's a very strange situation; there is *no* single solution for all platforms (which makes it really awkward). For one of our projects, we needed read-only support for MS-SQL Server (just for importing data); we ended up writing a very simple CakePHP DataSource using [`mssql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) for Linux and [`sqlsrv_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) for some Windows workstations. There *may* be other solutions, but (as said) for our situation we managed to 'get it working', but it is far from ideal